# Есть ли для django модули для работы с веб-камерой?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Есть ли для django модули для работы с веб-камерой? Python3

Comment: Первая ссылка в гугле [Django-webcam](https://github.com/saxix/django-webcam)

Comment: У этого модуля нет поддержки python3. Давай вторую ссылку из google))